Can't use i18n with next.js
I have a Next.js 14.2.12 app that works fine. I've been trying to add i18n to it so it can be viewed in both Valencian and Spanish, but it seems like I always end up getting the same error:
TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createContext) is not a function
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/react-i18next/dist/es/context.js:22:73)
    at (rsc)/./node_modules/react-i18next/dist/es/context.js (C:\Users\olamelas\WebstormProjects\nomenclator\.next\server\vendor-chunks\react-i18next.js:210:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\olamelas\WebstormProjects\nomenclator\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/react-i18next/dist/es/Trans.js:8:69)
    at (rsc)/./node_modules/react-i18next/dist/es/Trans.js (C:\Users\olamelas\WebstormProjects\nomenclator\.next\server\vendor-chunks\react-i18next.js:180:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\olamelas\WebstormProjects\nomenclator\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/react-i18next/dist/es/index.js:26:67)
    at (rsc)/./node_modules/react-i18next/dist/es/index.js (C:\Users\olamelas\WebstormProjects\nomenclator\.next\server\vendor-chunks\react-i18next.js:240:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\olamelas\WebstormProjects\nomenclator\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/[locale]/layout.tsx:15:71) {
  type: 'TypeError',
  page: '/favicon.ico'

I've tried multiple ways and right now I have the following:
File structure:

Layout.tsx (Outer-most file, server component):
import {headers} from 'next/headers';
import {Suspense} from 'react';
import Header from '@/components/header/HeaderComponent';
import Footer from '@/components/footer/FooterComponent';
import './globals.css';
import {Spinner} from "react-bootstrap";
import {I18nextProvider} from 'react-i18next';
import i18next from "@/../i18n";

export const metadata = {
    title: 'Some title',
    description: 'Some desc',
};

export default function RootLayout({children}: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    const requestHeaders = headers();
    const locale = requestHeaders.get('accept-language')?.split(',')[0].slice(0, 2) || 'va';

    i18next.changeLanguage(locale);

    return (
        <I18nextProvider i18n={i18next}>
            <html lang={locale}>
            <body>
            <Suspense fallback={<Spinner/>}>
                <Header/>
                <div style={{width: '80%', minHeight: '60vh', margin: '0 auto'}}>
                    {children}
                </div>
                <Footer/>
            </Suspense>
            </body>
            </html>
        </I18nextProvider>
    );
}

middleware.js:
import {NextResponse} from "next/server";

export function middleware(request) {
    const locale = request.headers.get('accept-language')?.split(',')[0].slice(0, 2) || 'va';
    const response = NextResponse.next();
    response.cookies.set('NEXT_LOCALE', locale);
    return response;
}

export const config = {
    matcher: '/\\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/'
}

next-i18next.config.mjs:
const config = {
    i18n: {
        defaultLocale: 'va',
        locales: ['es', 'va'],
    },
};

export default config;

i18n.ts:
import i18next from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import esTranslations from './public/locales/es/common.json';
import vaTranslations from './public/locales/va/common.json';

i18next
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        lng: 'va',
        fallbackLng: 'va',
        resources: {
            es: {
                translation: esTranslations,
            },
            ca: {
                translation: vaTranslations,
            },
        },
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false,
        },
    });

export default i18next;

next.config.mjs:
import nextI18nextConfig from "./next-i18next.config.mjs";

const nextConfig = {
    i18n: nextI18nextConfig.i18n,
};

I'm completely lost at this point, any help is welcome
export default nextConfig;

You are trying to use a client component in a server component.
Add "use client" at the top of your layout.
Or alternatively, create a new file Providers.tsx :
"use client"

import {I18nextProvider} from 'react-i18next';

import i18next from "@/../i18n";

export function Providers({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return <I18nextProvider i18n={i18next}>{children}</I18nextProvider>;
}

And in your layout

import { Providers } from "./Providers";

export default function RootLayout({children}: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const requestHeaders = headers();
  const locale = requestHeaders.get('accept-language')?.split(',')[0].slice(0, 2) || 'va';
  i18next.changeLanguage(locale);
  return (
      <Providers>
          <html lang={locale}>
          <body>
          <Suspense fallback={<Spinner/>}>
              <Header/>
              <div style={{width: '80%', minHeight: '60vh', margin: '0 auto'}}>
                  {children}
              </div>
              <Footer/>
          </Suspense>
          </body>
          </html>
      </Providers>
  );
}


Making it a client component was not an option. I ended up kind of making it work with next-intl instead, but there are still some issues I need to address...
